# Error 500 Backoffice prestashop 1.7

Tags: prestashop, prestashop1.7

vengo por aqui con un problema que no logro resolver.

Tengo un prestashop en version 1.7 que he mudado a otro servidor, cabe mencionar que en el servidor viejo el prestashop esta funcionando bien.

Cuando he migrado el prestashop al nuevo servidor, todo funciona bien excepto cuando quiero entrar al Backoffice, cuando quiero entrar al Backoffice, simplemente queda la pagina en blanco.

He activado el modo debug, pero no me arroja ningun error referente a Backoffice, lo interesante es que cuando se activa el modo debug, puedo entrar sin problema al Backoffice.

Lo unico que puedo ver es que me da un error 500 pero no me dice mas nada.

No se si alguien pueda darme alguna idea de lo que puede estar sucediendo para este caso, Gracias.

Comment: Si puedes entrar al back-end en ese modo, lo mejor que puedes hacer es regenerar el htaccess en el apartado de seo y url del back-end. Prueba con eso y por supuesto, antes de todo, limpia la cache de navegadores y de prestashop.

Comment: Considera repasar el fichero error.log generado en el servidor ya que muy probablemente ahí esté la solución.

Answer (score 0):

Yo me encontré con este tipo de problemas al iniciar con prestashop 1.7.x, en las versiones 1.6.x nunca tuve ese error, comento alguna serie de cosas que debes asegurarte aunque algunas no aplican en tu caso desde el momento que dices que en `debug mode ON` si puedes acceder, no lo mencionas en tu pregunta pero si ya te aseguraste de los siguiente:

**1.** Que tu archivo `app/config/parameters.php` contenga las configuraciones de conexión a tu base de datos:

eje:

```
<?php return array (
  'parameters' => 
  array (
    'database_host' => 'localhost',
    'database_port' => '',
    'database_name' => 'NOMBRE_BASEDATOS',
    'database_user' => 'NOMBRE_USUARIO', //con privilegios
    'database_password' => 'PASS_USUARIO', //con privilegios
    'database_prefix' => 'ps_', //el prefijo con que hayas instalado tu bd
    'database_engine' => 'InnoDB',
    'mailer_transport' => 'smtp',
    'mailer_host' => '127.0.0.1',
    'mailer_user' => NULL,
    'mailer_password' => NULL,
    'secret' => 'e1zETC',
    'ps_caching' => 'CacheMemcache',
    'ps_cache_enable' => false,
    'ps_creation_date' => '2021-06-14',
    'locale' => 'en-US',
    'use_debug_toolbar' => true,
    'cookie_key' => 'w3SsETC',
    'cookie_iv' => 'y2orrGAJ',
    'new_cookie_key' => 'defETC',
  ),
);
```

**2.** Asegurarte que en tu tabla `shop_url` de tu base de datos tengas configurado:

`domain -> tudominio.com`

`ssldomain-> tudominio.com`

`url-> /`

La URL debe ser la ubicacion fisica de tu website, si esta por defecto en la carpeta public, entonces con `/` es suficiente.

**3.** Eliminar el cache de tu sitio de forma manual (en caso de no poder acceder al backoffice)

ve a la ruta `var>cache` dentro de aqui encontraras 2 carpetas `prod & dev`, realiza una copia de seguridad de ambas carpetas y luego eliminalas.

Carga nuevamente tu sitio web y con eso ya deberias poder acceder a tu sitio web tanto en `debug mode ON y OFF`

Saludos,